# QUERY & SUBQUERY OPTIMISATION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've this query. the problem is that it takes like 5min or more to be excecuted.
I'm using a subquery to bring me only values >200

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RATIO] @DATED nvarchar(30),@DATEF nvarchar(30), @REG nvarchar(30)

SELECT 
[REGION] = ET_REGION,
[MAGASIN] = ET2.ET_LIBELLE ,
(SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT GL_NUMERO)

FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM

LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET4 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET4.ET_ETABLISSEMENT

WHERE

CAST(GL_DATEPIECE AS DATE)  BETWEEN CAST(@DATED AS DATE) AND CAST(@DATEF AS DATE)
AND ET4.ET_LIBELLE = ET2.ET_LIBELLE
AND GP_TOTALTTC < 200
)'S : <200'

FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM

LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 

WHERE 
CAST(GL_DATEPIECE AS DATE)  BETWEEN CAST(@DATED AS DATE) AND CAST(@DATEF AS DATE)

GROUP BY
ET_REGION,
ET2.ET_LIBELLE
```

Comment: Please add the table prefixes to **ALL** columns. Maybe it's evident to you which table each column belongs to, but it's not evident for us. This is the second time you ask this question.

Comment: Please post the execution plan. You can do it by: `set showplan_text on; [Run your SQL here] set showplan_text off;`.

Comment: `CAST(GL_DATEPIECE AS DATE)` - a bad part. Do you have any index on that column? Due to the converting the index cant be used to perform seek operations.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin that depends. Converting a datetime to a date is actually SARGable. One of those rare times you can get away with it.

Comment: That alias 'S : <200' is just crazy. You really should use an alias that makes sense and does not have spaces and other non alphanumeric characters. This query is not all that complicated but the lack of formatting makes this way more difficult to read than it needs to be.

Comment: @SeanLange, I'm not able to remember one case from my practice, maybe it's possible when all values have 00:00:00 as its time part. I'll try to test it.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin here is a great question and discussion with other links on this topic. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea

Answer (score 0):

It's tough doing this without the underlying data but from what I can read of what you're doing then something like this might do it for you;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RATIO] @DATED nvarchar(30),@DATEF nvarchar(30), @REG nvarchar(30)
AS
DECLARE @DATED_Date DATE = @DATED;
DECLARE @DATEF_Date DATE = @DATEF;

SELECT 
    [REGION] = ET_REGION,
    [MAGASIN] = ET2.ET_LIBELLE ,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN GP_TOTALTTC < 200 THEN GL_NUMERO END) AS 'S : <200'
FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
WHERE CAST(GL_DATEPIECE AS DATE)  BETWEEN @DATED_Date AND @DATEF_Date
GROUP BY ET_REGION, ET2.ET_LIBELLE
```

Comment: I can't really picture what is the improvement. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, there's no subquery in the select statement (which suck for performance as they get executed for each row in the final query) and no unnecessary hitting of tables multiple times